# altERnaTIng cAsE JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Нужно поменять регистр у каждой буквы в строке. Например:
"hello WORLD" - "HELLO world"
"HeLLo WoRLD" - "hEllO wOrld"
Вот, что сделал я. Помогите найти ошибку.

```js
let str = prompt();
let str1 = str;

str = str.toLowerCase();

for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] === str1[i]) {
    str1[i] = str1[i].toUpperCase()
  } else {
    str1[i] = str1[i].toLowerCase()
  }
}

console.log(str1);
```

Comment: строки в javascript неизменяемы

Answer (score 2):

```js
    let str = prompt();
    let str1 = '';
    for (let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        var up = str[i].toUpperCase()==str[i];
        if(up == true){
            str1 += str[i].toLowerCase();
        } else{
            str1 += str[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    console.log(str1);
```